# PHP Empty $_POST

Tags: php, apache, http, post, http-headers

I am sending data to PHP through HTTP POST. This works fine for data shorter than 8MB (8192KB), however when higher quantities of data are sent, PHP shows the `$_POST` variable to be empty. I emphasize that the `$_POST` variable does not even contain the names of the post fields, it exists as an empty array. The critical point seems to be between 8.0MB and 9.0MB, and continues higher of course.

I have attempted the following with no success:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '220M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '220M');
```

I require the data to pass through HTTP POST. The data cannot be uploaded as a file.

Also could Apache be responsible for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 8MB = 1024KB? Really? Last time I checked it was 8192KB... 8Mb (mega **bits**) are 1024KB (kilo **bytes**) but this is pretty irrelevant in terms of PHP/Apache...

Comment: Do you have an access to modify these settings via ini_set?

Comment: @Michael Sazonov I can change the maximum execution time through ini_set like this `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`. So I assume yes.

Comment: @Michael Sazonov there is no .htaccess.

Comment: `ini_set('post_max_size', '220M');` and `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '220M');` won't work in php script because they are applied after getting file by PHP. You should define them in php.ini or in .htaccess or in vhost config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the [documentation comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php#22264). when the script is executed, itäs too late to change sopme setting, wich includes `post_max_size`, for example. to change these values, try to use a `.htaccess`-file like this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
```

or change these settings directly in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 4):

This will help

[What are the caveats with increasing max_post_size and upload_max_filesize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752644/what-are-the-caveats-with-increasing-max-post-size-and-upload-max-filesize)

And maybe

http://blurringexistence.net/archives/11-PHPs-max_post_size.html

Answer (score 0):

`post_max_size` is, according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling), defined as a `PHP_INI_PERDIR` setting. It can be set in your php.ini or .htaccess file. A definition for `PHP_INI_PERDIR` is given here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Settings that are defined as `PHP_INI_ALL` *can* be set with `ini_set()`.